# why My app crashes "Access to Bad" when I am pushing controllers i UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Hi all
why My app crashes "Access to Bad" when I am pushing controllers in  UINavigationController
I am also using some static variables to store data.
Please help 
I am using UINavigationController , and I push many controllers in it ,but some time my app crashed saying "Access to the bad Request" ,Is this happening due to static variables ?

Comment: Please ask your question more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because you accessing some released object